# How can i position a submenu to the right of main menu?

Tags: html, css

I want to position the submenu items a bit to the right of the main menu. Currently I have,

```
<MenuItem title="Main">
    <SubMenu>
       <a href="/Name">Name Details</a>
       <a href="/Details">Cust Details</a>                                                
    </SubMenu>
</MenuItem>
```

At the moment the Name Details and Cust Details appear to the left of the Main heading.

How can I make it so that the submenus appears to the right of the main menu?

Comment: Hello, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and please add the efforts which you tried and what didn't work well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provided too little specific code.

Is this the effect you wanted?

```html
<style>
  MenuItem {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
  }

  SubMenu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: dodgerblue;
  }

  SubMenu a {
    margin: 5px;
    display: block;
  }
</style>
<body>
<MenuItem title="Main">
  <div class="title">Main</div>
  <SubMenu>
    <a href="/Name">Name Details</a>
    <a href="/Details">Cust Details</a>
  </SubMenu>
</MenuItem>
</body>
```

Comment: almost , the submenu should be under the main menu but to the right , not beside

Comment: @Belinda you can modify css attributes **top:** and **left:** in **SubMenu selector**